# Download Zoom Recordings to Local Machine and use Resumable Upload Method to upload the video to Google Drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I have built a function in Python3 that will retrieve the data from a Google Spreadsheet. The data will contain the Recording's Download_URL and other information.

The function will download the Recording and store it in the local machine. Once the video is saved, the function will upload it to Google Drive using the Resumable Upload method.

Even though the response from the Resumable Upload method is 200 and it also gives me the Id of the file, I can't seem to find the file anywhere in my Google Drive. Below is my code.

```py
import os
import requests
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY = 'Parent_Folder'

def upload_recording(file_location,file_name):
    filesize = os.path.getsize(file_location)

    # Retrieve session for resumable upload.

    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
    params = {
        "name": file_name,
        "mimeType": "video/mp4"
    }
    r = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(params)
    )
    print(r)
    location = r.headers['Location']

    # Upload the file.

    headers = {"Content-Range": "bytes 0-" + str(filesize - 1) + "/" + str(filesize)}
    r = requests.put(
        location,
        headers=headers,
        data=open(file_location, 'rb')
    )
    print(r.text)
    return True

def download_recording(download_url, foldername, filename):
    upload_success = False
    dl_dir = os.sep.join([DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY, foldername])
    full_filename = os.sep.join([dl_dir, filename])
    os.makedirs(dl_dir, exist_ok=True)

    response = requests.get(download_url, stream=True)
    try:
        with open(full_filename, 'wb') as fd:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512 * 1024):
                fd.write(chunk)
        upload_success = upload_recording(full_filename,filename)
        return upload_success
    except Exception as e:
        # if there was some exception, print the error and return False
        print(e)
        return upload_success

def main():
    scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet = client.open("Zoom Recordings Data").sheet1
    data = sheet.get_all_records()

    # Get the Recordings information that are needed to download
    for index in range(len(sheet.col_values(9))+1 ,len(data)+2):
        success = False
        getRow = sheet.row_values(index)
        session_name = getRow[0]
        topic = getRow[1]
        topic = topic.replace('/', '')
        topic = topic.replace(':', '')
        account_name = getRow[2]
        start_date = getRow[3]
        file_size = getRow[4]
        file_type = getRow[5]
        url_token = getRow[6] + '?access_token=' + getRow[7]

        file_name = start_date + ' - ' + topic + '.' + file_type.lower()
        file_destination = session_name + '/' + account_name + '/' + topic

        success |= download_recording(url_token, file_destination, file_name)

        # Update status on Google Sheet
        if success:
            cell = 'I' + str(index)
            sheet.update_acell(cell,'success')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        'creds.json',
        scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    )

    delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('Service_Account_client_email')

    access_token = delegated_credentials.get_access_token().access_token
    main()
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to upload the video to the folder that it needs to be. I'm very new to Python and the Drive API. I would very appreciate if you can give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Issue and solution:

> Even though the response from the Resumable Upload method is 200 and it also gives me the Id of the file, I can't seem to find the file anywhere in my Google Drive. Below is my code.

I think that your script is correct for the resumable upload. From your above situation and from your script, I understood that your script worked, and the file has been able to be uploaded to Google Drive with the resumable upload.

And, when I saw your issue of `I can't seem to find the file anywhere in my Google Drive` and your script, I noticed that you are uploading the file using the access token retrieved by the service account. In this case, the uploaded file is put to the Drive of the service account. Your Google Drive is different from the Drive of the service account. By this, you cannot see the uploaded file using the browser. In this case, I would like to propose the following 2 methods.

### Pattern 1:

The owner of the uploaded file is the service account. In this pattern, share the uploaded file with your Google account. The function `upload_recording` is modified as follows. And please set your email address of Google account to `emailAddress`.

#### Modified script:

```
def upload_recording(file_location, file_name):
    filesize = os.path.getsize(file_location)

    # Retrieve session for resumable upload.

    headers1 = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}  # Modified
    params = {
        "name": file_name,
        "mimeType": "video/mp4"
    }
    r = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
        headers=headers1,  # Modified
        data=json.dumps(params)
    )
    print(r)
    location = r.headers['Location']

    # Upload the file.

    headers2 = {"Content-Range": "bytes 0-" + str(filesize - 1) + "/" + str(filesize)}  # Modified
    r = requests.put(
        location,
        headers=headers2,  # Modified
        data=open(file_location, 'rb')
    )

    # I added below script.
    fileId = r.json()['id']
    permissions = {
        "role": "writer",
        "type": "user",
        "emailAddress": "###"  # <--- Please set your email address of your Google account.
    }
    r2 = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "/permissions",
        headers=headers1,
        data=json.dumps(permissions)
    )
    print(r2.text)
    return True
```

- When you run above modified script, you can see the uploaded file at "Shared with me" of your Google Drive.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the file is uploaded to the shared folder using the resumable upload with the service account. So **at first, please prepare a folder in your Google Drive and share the folder with the email of the service account.**

#### Modified script:

Please modify the function `upload_recording` as follows. And please set the folder ID you shared with the service account.

From:

```
params = {
    "name": file_name,
    "mimeType": "video/mp4"
}
```

To:

```
params = {
    "name": file_name,
    "mimeType": "video/mp4",
    "parents": ["###"]  # <--- Please set the folder ID you shared with the service account.
}
```

- When you run above modified script, you can see the uploaded file at the shared folder of your Google Drive.

### Note:

- In this case, the owner is the service account. Of course, the owner can be also changed.

### Reference:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my every single post. I finally completed the project. You are the best!

Comment: @Anh Nguyen Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.